# Trying to use Dense_Rank in a Case statement on a calculated column

Tags: sql, case, dense-rank

In an effort to improve my SQL skills I am working on a database of baseball statistics at home.  I am using a calculated field to get the batting average and I am trying to use dense_rank on that field.  I want to exclude any players with less than 150 at bats so I put Dense_rank in a Case statement. It worked when I did it on the Hits column but not on the Avg field (which is a calculated field).  It works when not in a Case statement (commented out in the query, pasted below) but when you put it in a Case statement it returns the same value for everything.  I have pasted the entire query below and I put a **** by the relevant piece so you can find it.  Any suggestions?

```
select 
    distinct b.playerid
    ,m.namelast +', '+ m.namefirst 'Player Name'
    ,case
        when t.name = 'Florida Marlins'
        then 'Miami Marlins'
        else t.name
        end Team
    ,case b.lgid
        when 'NL' then 'National'
        when 'AL' then 'American'
        else b.lgid 
        end League
    ,b.yearid Year
    ,case 
        when y.POS in ('LF','RF','CF') 
        then 'OF' 
        else y.pos end Position
    ,b.g G,b.AB
    ,b.h Hits
    ,dense_rank() over 
        (partition by t.name, b.yearid order by 
            case
                when b.ab>='150'
                then b.h
                end desc
                ) 'Hit Rank'
    ,cast(isnull(cast(b.h as numeric)/nullif(cast(b.ab as numeric),0),0) as decimal(10,3)) 'Avg.'
****    ,dense_rank() over 
        (partition by t.name, b.yearid order by
         --cast(isnull(cast(b.h as numeric)/nullif(cast(b.ab as numeric),0),0) as decimal(10,3)) desc
            case
                when b.ab>='150'
                then cast((isnull(cast(b.h as bigint)/nullif(cast(b.ab as bigint),0),0)*1000) as bigint)
                end desc
                ) 
                'AVG Rank'
    ,b.R,b.[2B],b.[3B] ,b.hr HR
    ,b.sb SB,b.cs CS,b.bb BB,b.so SO,b.ibb IBB,b.hbp HBP
from batting b
    join teams t on b.teamid=t.teamid and t.yearid=b.yearid and t.lgid=b.lgid
    join master m on b.playerid=m.playerid
    join fielding f on b.playerid=f.playerid and b.yearid=f.yearid and b.teamid=f.teamid and m.playerid=f.playerid and f.teamid=t.teamid
    join    
        (
        select f.playerid, f.yearid, f.teamid, f.pos, isnull(f.po,0) PO, isnull(f.a,0) A, isnull(f.e,0) E, isnull(f.dp,0) DP, isnull(f.g,0) G, isnull(f.innouts,0) innouts
        ,(isnull(f.po,0)+ isnull(f.a,0)+ isnull(f.e,0)+ isnull(f.dp,0)+ isnull(f.g,0)+ isnull(f.innouts,0)) Total
        from fielding f
            join    
                (
                select playerid, yearid, max(po) PO, max(g) G, isnull(max(innouts),0) innouts
                ,(isnull(po,0) + isnull(a,0) + isnull(e,0) + isnull(dp,0) + isnull(g,0) + isnull(innouts,0)) Total
                from fielding
                group by playerid, yearid, po, a, e, dp, g, innouts
                ) z on f.playerid=z.playerid and f.yearid=z.yearid
        group by f.playerid, f.yearid, f.stint, f.teamid, f.pos, f.po, f.a, f.e, f.dp, f.g, f.innouts
        having (isnull(f.po,0)+ isnull(f.a,0)+ isnull(f.e,0)+ isnull(f.dp,0)+ isnull(f.g,0)+ isnull(f.innouts,0))=max(z.total)
        ) y on f.playerid=y.playerid and f.yearid=y.yearid
where
    b.yearid='2015'
    and t.name='new york mets'
order by
    12,4,3,5,2
```

Comment: Try simplifying your query and explaining exactly what the problem is.  Your question is quite unclear, and the long query just further confuses whatever point you want to make.

Comment: I know it is long, that's because I am playing around with it and learning how to do different things,  I'm trying to figure out why Dense_Rank returns a value of 1 for everything (actually a 1 for everything with At Bats > 150 and a 2 for everything else) when its included in a Case Statement.  The relevant piece is in the Select statement so you shouldn't have to look at anything below that.

Comment: Your average calculations are different, the failing one uses INTEGER division, which results in zero for all rows. Simply use the calculation based on `numeric` instead

Comment: Perfect - That's it.  Thanks,

Comment: @dnoeth . . . You might consider adding your comment as an answer.